# Linq to SQL to return parent rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a table format of

```
Id (int)
ParentId (int)
```

I need to query out all rows that are related to each other so ParentId = Id but nested multiple times

I am a bit stuck on how to tackle this one, I may revert to a stored procedure but I really wanted to try this in pure linq to sql.

Comment: apologies that is what I mean by I am a bit stuck.  Not sure how to go about this in the slightest.

Comment: If I need to revert to SQL then I can manage that part fine.  It's more a case of it's preferred to be in linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have 2 options:

- You have to explicitly fetch parents which causes many separate calls to db. I think this kind of architecture (to fetch self-referencing data recursively with one call from db) is not supported in L2S or L2E.
- In these scenarios, I tend to use native capabilities of my db (in this case: [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)). You can use your custom sql queries and also define return types with `db.ExecuteQuery<ReturnType>`. If you're on sql server 2005+ you can use the following syntax:

  `var allGroups =

                      db.ExecuteQuery(

                      @"WITH n(Id, ParentId) AS

                      (SELECT Id, ParentId

                      FROM MyTable

                      WHERE Id = {0}

                      UNION ALL

                      SELECT nplus1.Id, nplus1.ParentId

                      FROM MyTable as nplus1, n

                      WHERE n.ParentId = nplus1.Id)

                      SELECT Id, ParentId FROM n",

                      firstChildId).ToList();`

This way, you have fetched all entities in one call.  Check out [How to do an upper recursive self-join in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780886/how-to-do-an-upper-recursive-self-join-in-sql-server) and [Simplest way to do a recursive self-join in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757260/simplest-way-to-do-a-recursive-self-join-in-sql-server).

Comment: I have been searching and trying things and like you said it always results in multiple calls to the db which is not good.  I think I will revert to a procedure like I mentioned as we defiantly don't want SQL code in the library just in case we need to use mysql/oracle in the future (there is a high chance).  I will accept your answer as you also gave extra information on the SQL and the routine would work in linq.